# Remove Extra Lines in Excel Sheet Using VB and .cmd

Tags: excel, batch-file, vb6, runtime

I have a large excel sheet with a log that consists of around 30000 entries.

The programmer before me has created a `removeline.cmd` file to remove all extra blank lines in a certain column for the excel file.

The code for the `RemoveLine.cmd`:

```
   cls
   cd\ 
   SET vbfile=newlinetest.exe
   K:
   cd "IPM - CompOps\Ops Docs\avail-stats\Originals"
   %vbfile%
   exit
```

The file runs correctly but at the end it displays this error, which is essentially what I'm trying to get rid of:

```
   Run-time error '1004';

   Method '~' of object '~' failed
```

**EDIT:**
the program `newlinetest.exe` was written in VB6 (I have access to it on my machine).
The full source-code for `newline.frm` is:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.Form Form1
Caption = "Form1"
ClientHeight = 4500
ClientLeft = 3435
ClientTop = 3585
ClientWidth = 5175
LinkTopic = "Form1"
ScaleHeight = 4500
ScaleWidth = 5175
Begin VB.CommandButton Command1
Caption = "Excel"
Height = 495
Left = 1800
TabIndex = 0
Top = 3720
Width = 855
End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Form1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim oXL As Object ' Excel application
Dim oBook As Object ' Excel workbook
Dim oSheet As Object ' Excel Worksheet
Dim oChart As Object ' Excel Chart

Dim year As String

Dim i As Long

Dim MyRowNumber As Long

Dim Row As Long

Dim comment As String, newline As String

Dim curDate As String

Open "K:\IPM - CompOps\Ops Docs\avail-stats\Originals\Inputavailfile.txt" For Input As #1

Input #1, Data

Close #1




'Start Excel and create a new workbook
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
oXL.Visible = True
oXL.UserControl = True

year = Format(Now, "yyyy")

curDate = Date - 3

curDate = Format(curDate, "m/d/yyyy")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open FileName:="K:\IPM - CompOps\Ops Docs\avail-stats\Originals\" + Data

Myfile = "K:\IPM - CompOps\Ops Docs\avail-stats\Originals\" + Data

On Error GoTo Handler
vOurResult = Cells.Find(What:=curDate, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

If (vOurResult = True) Then

MyRowNumber = ActiveCell.Row

Set ExcelLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)

'MsgBox vOurResult

Row = ExcelLastCell.Row
col = ExcelLastCell.Column

' MsgBox curDate

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 6).Select



comment = ActiveCell.Text

newline = Replace(comment, Chr(10), " ")

ActiveCell.Value = newline


For i = MyRowNumber To Row - 1

comment = ""
newline = ""

Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select

comment = ActiveCell.Text

newline = Replace(comment, Chr(10), " ")

ActiveCell.Value = newline

Next i

'MsgBox curDate


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Myfile, FileFormat:=xlNormal

End If
oXL.Quit

Handler:
oXL.Quit

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Command1_Click





End
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have these lines towards the end of the Sub:

```
oXL.Quit

Handler:
oXL.Quit
```

The second `Quit` call fails, generating the error. You need to exit the procedure just before the Handler (which will only be called in the event of an error):

```
oXL.Quit
Exit Sub

Handler:
oXL.Quit
```

Comment: like this? ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Myfile, FileFormat:=xlNormal
        
 End If
oXL.Quit
Exit Sub

Handler:
oXL.Quit

 End Sub

Comment: It is hard to tell without any line breaks but, yes, like that. Try it.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not very chatty. Maybe someone else will contribute, who might examine your code in more detail than I have. As you have the original code, you could test it from VB6 and get a more helpful error message (and can step through the code).

Comment: I do have another suggestion, but I don't think you'll like it :). Re-write the VB6 code in a VBScript or as VBA in Excel. Soz, but good luck.

Comment: @omarK: based on our chat (before you re-posted your question) I must ask.. did you compile the source to a new exe and test that new exe? Also, could it be that your company runs a newer version of excel (one that was not yet available yet when the previous programmer wrote the exe), aka, when did the error's start?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code 'falls through' to your `line-label` called `Handler`.
Thus when your `Handler` then tries to call `Method 'Quit' of object 'oXL'`, that will fail because oXL has already quit.

The obvious solution is to `Exit Sub` before it reaches the `Handler`.

The general layout for a Sub (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)):

```
Sub InitializeMatrix(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   . . .
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   . . .
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Seems the original question that I was helping the asker with via [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33373/discussion-between-gitaarlab-and-omar-k) was deleted and later re-posted (I assume to get some fresh page-views).
Although Andy G has already answered this re-post, I figured not to let my answer go to waste and posted it anyway, hoping the explanation and reference might help future readers.